# Python suds error creating object

Tags: python, soap, suds

Trying to work with the echosign SOAP API.

The wsdl is here: https://secure.echosign.com/services/EchoSignDocumentService14?wsdl

When I try to create certain objects, it appears to not be able to find the type, even after listing it in `print client`

```
import suds

url = "https://secure.echosign.com/services/EchoSignDocumentService14?wsdl"

client = suds.client.Client(url)
print client


  Service ( EchoSignDocumentService14 ) tns="http://api.echosign"
     Prefixes (10)
        ns0 = "http://api.echosign"
        ns1 = "http://dto.api.echosign"
        ns2 = "http://dto10.api.echosign"
        ns3 = "http://dto11.api.echosign"
        ns4 = "http://dto12.api.echosign"
        ns5 = "http://dto13.api.echosign"
        ns15 = "http://dto14.api.echosign"
        ns16 = "http://dto7.api.echosign"
        ns17 = "http://dto8.api.echosign"
        ns18 = "http://dto9.api.echosign"
     Ports (1):
        (EchoSignDocumentService14HttpPort)
           Methods (45):
                 ...
           Types (146):
              ns1:CallbackInfo
              ns17:WidgetCreationInfo
```

Trimmed for brevity, but showing the namespaces and the 2 types I'm concerned with right now.

Trying to run `WCI = client.factory.create("ns17:WidgetCreationInfo")` generates this error:

> > > client.factory.create("ns17:WidgetCreationInfo")
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/suds/client.py", line 244, in create
> > >       suds.BuildError: 
> > >               An error occured while building a instance of (ns17:WidgetCreationInfo).  As a result
> > >               the object you requested could not be constructed.  It is recommended
> > >               that you construct the type manually using a Suds object.
> > >               Please open a ticket with a description of this error.
> > >               Reason: Type not found: '(CallbackInfo, http://dto.api.echosign, )'

So it doesn't appear to be able to find the CallbackInfo type. Maybe its because its missing the ns there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Again, figured it out 15 min after posting here.

suds has an option to cross-pollinate all the namespaces so they all import each others schemas. `autoblend` can be set in the constructor or using the `set_options` method.

```
suds.client.Client(url, autoblend=True)
```

Comment: This just saved me! Although I keep getting errorCode = "EXCEPTION" when actually trying to create the embedded widget. Did it work for you?

Comment: Yes. They don't exactly provide much information in their errorMessage do they? I got that until I formatted the request exactly right. Here's a working example (I tried both the url and passing the encoded file which is commented out, both work) https://gist.github.com/3140960

Comment: Also, you might not have to explicitly `None` out all those properties, but I believe you do for some.

Comment: Wow, thanks! That did the trick. I was setting fileInfos = [fileInfo] instead of creating the ArrayOfFileInfo

Comment: I did the same thing at first. :) They don't have the most graceful API. I mean... SOAP? Its 2012 guys.

Comment: SOAP is the fax of the internet world. Which is why its used for e-signing docs ;) I've given up on using the widgets, btw, since I cant seem to programmatically get a URL to the signed document. Gonna try sendDocumentInteractive instead...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in the WSDL, it seems lots of definitions in http://*.api.echosign that suds cannot fetch.

Either update your /etc/hosts to make these not well-formed domains can be reached, or save the wsdl locally, modify it, then use Client('file://...', ...) to create your suds client.

Comment: I believe its fetching them all fine.